# getting position of database item from non list view view?

Tags: android, eclipse, view, android-view

I have Views that show info from a database using a get cursor method. What I want to know is how to get the position id, like you would in a listview. they have the AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();, item being MenuItem, type of method the problem is it doesn't seem to work in just a regular view. Is there a method similar to the AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); for just a regular view?

**Edit**

**log cat**

```
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at www.theapp.co.hours.html.ViewHours.onClick(ViewHours.java:6041)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-14 08:55:43.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is stopping you to just add the `_id` column to the query that returns the cursor used by that simple view?

Comment: @slukian, I have an _id column, I get a nullPointerException on AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();... I will add my logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a method similar to the AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); for just a regular view?

No. If you, say, elect to pour `Cursor` data in to a `TextView`, you need to track what position or `_id` you used yourself. After all, **you** were the one who chose which position or `_id` to move to -- Android has no way of knowing if you populate a `TextView` from a `Cursor` or something else.